# document.getElementById('------').value showing undefined

Tags: javascript, laravel

Good Evening.
I am working on home based project and new learner to the Laravel and coding.

Here i am trying to get the Card header value in ajax to pass controller and get data from the same.

Card header showing the month name which is in loop.

here is the code

```
@foreach ($totalmilkselldataforyeartotable as $item)

  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-lg-2">
        <div class="card border-success " style="width: 12rem;">
            <div class="card-header">
              <span id="monthnameforcard"> <strong>{{ $item['monthname'] }}</strong>  </span> 
            </div>
              <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <li class="list-group-item">Total Milk - &nbsp;<strong>{{ $item['totalmilk'] }}</strong></li>
                                                                
              </ul>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">
                <span id="getmonthmilkdetails" class='glyphicon glyphicon'> More <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> </span>
            </button>
        </div>

    </div>

@endforeach
```

code for Ajax.

```
$(document).on('click', '#getmonthmilkdetails', function() {

                    var getmonthnameforajax = document.getElementById('monthnameforcard').value; 

                    alert(getmonthnameforajax);

                    $.ajax({

                        type: 'post',
                        url: '/getmonthmilkdetails',
                        data: {
                            '_token'            : $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                            'monthname'         : getmonthnameforajax,
                        },

                        success: function(data) {

                                

                        }
                    });


                });
```

alert box showing "Undefined "

Thanks for help

Comment: A `span` does not have a `value`. Are you looking for [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText)? Also, if you're creating HTML elements in a loop, you need to assign unique IDs, as you can't have multiple elements with the same `monthnameforcard` or `getmonthmilkdetails` id.

Comment: `document.getElementById('monthnameforcard').value;` won't work for a `<span>` element; `.value` is for `<input>`, `<select>`, etc. elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use `class` instead of `id` and use `closest` to get the parent element that has `card` class then use `querySelector` to get the element has `monthnameforcard` class

```
@foreach ($totalmilkselldataforyeartotable as $item)

  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-lg-2">
        <div class="card border-success " style="width: 12rem;">
            <div class="card-header">
              <span class="monthnameforcard"> <strong>{{ $item['monthname'] }}</strong>  </span> 
            </div>
              <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <li class="list-group-item">Total Milk - &nbsp;<strong>{{ $item['totalmilk'] }}</strong></li>
                                                                
              </ul>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">
                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon getmonthmilkdetails'> More <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> </span>
            </button>
        </div>

    </div>

@endforeach
```

```
$(document).on('click', '#getmonthmilkdetails', function(E) {

                    var getmonthnameforajax = e.currentTarget.closest('.card').querySelector('.monthnameforcard').textContent;
                    alert(getmonthnameforajax);

                    $.ajax({

                        type: 'post',
                        url: '/getmonthmilkdetails',
                        data: {
                            '_token'            : $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                            'monthname'         : getmonthnameforajax,
                        },

                        success: function(data) {

                                

                        }
                    });


                });
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem with non-unique `id` values.

Comment: Its working. Thanks a lot. But now its showing value "April-22" for all 12 card. I need it should take the card header value. say 1st box "April-22" second - "May-22" and so on. I think i am messing at foreach loop. Can u point where did i am making the mistake.

Comment: ^ And this is why you need the unique ids, or a different way to get the right element.

Comment: Thanks. Can u explain more about how can i do the same.....

Comment: @Cerbrus, Yes, I didn't notice the loop.

Comment: Thanks... Getting Error - Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Element': '. monthnameforcard' is not a valid selector.

Comment: @RahulW Sorry, there are a space between the `dot` and `monthnameforcard` please remove it, I update the answer.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for delay reply....Working fine now..... Thanks Again